# How to create a numpy array from two lists of tuples, but only when the tuples are the same

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For image analysis i loaded up a float image with scipy imread.

Next, i had scipys argrelmax search for local maxima in axis 0 and 1 and stored the results as arrays of tuples.

```
data = msc.imread(prediction1, 'F')
datarelmax_0 = almax(data, axis = 0)
datarelmax_1 = almax(data, axis = 1)
```

how can i create a numpy array from both lists which contains only the tuples that are in both list?
Edit:
argrelmax creates a tuple with two arrays:

```
datarelmax_0 = ([1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10])
datarelmax_1 = ([11,2,13,14,5], [11,7,13,14,10])
```

in want to create a numpy array that looks like:

```
result_ar[(2,7),(5,10)]
```

Comment: Create sample numeric data and show us the expected output with explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this "naive" way?

```
import numpy as np

result = np.array([x for x in datarelmax_0 if x in datarelmax_1])
```

Pretty simple. Maybe there's a better/faster/fancier way by using some numpy methods but this should work for now.

EDIT: 
To answer your edited question, you can do this:

```
result = [x for x in zip(datarelmax_0[0], datarelmax_0[1]) if x in zip(datarelmax_1[0], datarelmax_1[1])]
```

This gives you

```
result = [(2, 7), (5, 10)]
```

If you convert it to a numpy array by using

```
result = np.array(result)
```

it looks like this:

```
 result = array([[ 2,  7],
                 [ 5, 10]])
```

In case you are interested in what zip does:

```
>>> zip(datarelmax_0[0], datarelmax_0[1])
[(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10)]

>>> zip(datarelmax_1[0], datarelmax_1[1])
[(11, 11), (2, 7), (13, 13), (14, 14), (5, 10)]
```

Comment: This looks promising. can i have it look in both arrays(i edited my question, argrelmax produces a tuple with two array i think)?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks alot!